# Renaming Server File Error (http wrapper does not support renaming) [PHP]

Tags: php, file, rename

On my page users can upload documents, which will be saved in a user specific folder. the directories are stored in a url: `http://localhost/folder/user/documentA_user_timestamp.ext` inside a database.

Users can also delete a file, which deletes the file's entry inside the database but i want the file to be moved to a specified archive folder. However i always get this error message when the php rename() tries to do its work:

> http wrapper does not support renaming in...

I can't seem to get my head around the error message and figure out whats the cause for it

```
$filepath = $_POST['file'];
$archivePath = FILESYS_DOCS_ARCHIVE . basename($filepath);

if (!file_exists(FILESYS_DOCS_ARCHIVE)){
    mkdir(FILESYS_DOCS_ARCHIVE, 0777);
}

$success = rename($filepath, $archivePath);

if ($success){
    echo "SUCCess";
} else {
   echo $archivePath;
}
```

Comment: Does php shows some error? Did you check php error logs?

Comment: what is the value of `$filepath` and `$archivePath` when you call the rename command? I'm going to guess at least one of them contains a URL instead of a path on disk. Also please show the full error message, not a snippet from it. Thanks

Comment: @Sakezzz the error is already mentioned in the question...

Comment: @ADyson both values are urls: "http://localhost/folder/..." do i have to convert them to directory paths "C:/...." ?

Comment: yes you do. Otherwise it tries to make a HTTP request to that URL, and obviously you can't rename a file over HTTP. Don't forget PHP is executing on your server, so it has access to the server disk directly, no need to refer to it via URLs or anything at this point in the process.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, everythings working now

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$dir = str_replace('http://','',base_url());
rename($dir.'older filename', $dir.'/new filename' )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, for others to better understand it.